# Developing Windows Phone 8.1 apps in Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I want to dive in into developing windows store apps. I am using visual studio express 2013 for desktop and my OS is windows 8.1. But when I want to follow a simple hello world project and I want to create a new project I am already limited in some way. I have to go to Installed > (I want to use C#) Visual C# > Universal or Windows Apps or Windows Phone Apps. But none of these 3 points are available when I want to follow the tutorial. Do you have any suggestions why this might be the case ?

Comment: Which tutorial are you trying to follow?

Comment: Its in german: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/dn609832.aspx

Comment: You need Visual Studio Express for Windows. Find it here: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To develop Windows Phone 8.1 apps, you need Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows. You're using the version for Desktop which is why you don't see the necessary templates.

> You can use the tools in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows to
>   create innovative and compelling Windows Phone and Windows Store apps
>   on Windows 8.1.

You can find and download the Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx).

Comment: It took me a long time to install it, but it is finally done. Your answer was correct :)